# How can I add a custom Build Summary section from a script?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2013 XAML build process template that runs a PowerShell script (which pushes packages to NuGet).

The build activity `WriteCustomSummaryInformation` [was added in TFS2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/06/07/tfs11-rc-simple-build-summary-customization.aspx) for XAML builds. I'd like to use this same activity or implement the same functionality somehow from my script (so that I can show which packages were published). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by running the activity and looking at what it added to the build information.

```
Function New-CustomSummaryInformation($Build, $Message, $SectionHeader, $SectionName, $SectionPriority = 0)
{
    $CustomSummaryInformationType = 'CustomSummaryInformation'

    $root = $Build.Information.Nodes | ? { $_.Type -eq $CustomSummaryInformationType } | select -First 1
    if (!$root)
    {
        $root = $Build.Information.CreateNode()
        $root.Type = 'CustomSummaryInformation'
    }

    $node = $root.Children.CreateNode()
    $node.Type = 'CustomSummaryInformation'

    $node.Fields['Message'] = $Message
    $node.Fields['SectionHeader'] = $SectionHeader
    $node.Fields['SectionName'] = $SectionKeyName
    $node.Fields['SectionPriority'] = $SectionPriority
}

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client')
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client')
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client')

$workspaceInfo = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation]::Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo($env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY )
$tpc = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection $workspaceInfo.ServerUri
$vcs = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$buildServer = $tpc.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

$buildDef = $buildServer.GetBuildDefinition("MyProject", "MyBuildDefn")   
$build = $buildServer.GetBuild($def.LastBuildUri)
New-CustomSummaryInformation $build -Message "This is a test message" -SectionHeader "This is the header displayed" -SectionName "ThisIsAnInternalKey"

$build.Information.Save()
```